# Configuring XAMPP server to create a recursive copy?

Tags: php, sql, recursion, xampp, backup

I've got two separate servers, one called FREED and one called SALAMANDER. FREED occasionally has to go down for maintenance, which causes problems when trying to input data into my database. SALAMANDER is always up and does mostly menial tasks. What I would like to do is somehow allow for FREED to make a complete backup of XAMPP (PHP, SQL databases, etc) onto SALAMANDER so that when FREED goes down, the webserver and other services are still provided by SALAMANDER as a contingency.

Has anyone tried this? I wondered if symlinks would be a viable option. Any tips or suggestions on a project like this? Thanks!

Comment: Is this on your personal computer?  I really hope you are not using XAMPP for a production server, which is what it sounds like...

Comment: However, yes it is possible.  What OS are you running?

Comment: Nomistic, to answer your first question: yes, both of these servers are personal computers existing on a LAN without any connection to the internet unless I allow them. In response to your second question, on FREED (the primary server) I am running WinXP, and on SALAMANDER I am running Win8. Both are running the exact same version of XAMPP.

Comment: the easiest way of handling this would be this would be using an SQL dump on a periodic basis and then when it goes down, to upload the data to the other server.  You could also run a regular backup of your PHP files as well;  this all could be done with a batch file